Is there a hook to be able to edit a flag confirm form to add additional functionality?
I have a flag to report content as inappropriate, and when someone clicks on the "Report as Inappropriate" flag I want a confirmation to drop down with a title, some text, and the submit and "i've changed my mind" buttons. However with the flag module I can only add a "flag confirmation message" and edit the flagging button text but not the cancel confirmation button text.
Does anyone know if there is a hook to edit the flag confirmation form?
And if not if there is another way to edit it to add additional functionality?
I looked into the documentation on drupal.org but that all looked like it was for the D7 version of the flag module and I couldn't find anything that detailed API stuff for the D10 version of the module

The "detailed API stuff" for Drupal 8+ is in the comments on the various interfaces in the module code; there is no quick reference documentation like there is for Drupal 7, although I made an issue to add one.
For what you want to do, you could override FlagConfirmForm, or I think you can just use hook_form_alter and target the flag confirm form (it's been awhile since I've worked with flag, so I'm not 100% sure).
